# Firebase firestore query

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have 2 fields with other fields named '**uId**' and '**sellerUId**' in my collections as in the screenshot below. Both are Auth IDs. I want to filter **uId** == **auth_id** or **sellerUId** == **auth_id**.

[image]

I have tried the following query:

```
.doc('doc name')
  .collection('collection name')
  .where(['uId', 'sellerUId'], isEqualTo: 'auth_id')
  .get()
  .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
    for (var doc in querySnapshot.docs) {
      print(doc.id);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firestore does not support OR queries on multiple fields. You would need 2 different queries - one for `uid == auth_id` and another for `sellerUid == auth_id`.

For this use case, you can store a single array in the document `users` that contains both `userId` and `sellectUid` like this so you get fetch these documents in a single query:

```
{
  users: ["uid", "sellerUid"],
  ...otherFields
}
```

Then you can use [`array-contains`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#dart_6) operator:

```
.doc('doc name')
  .collection('collection name')
  .where("users", arrayContains: "auth_id");
  .get()
  .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
    for (var doc in querySnapshot.docs) {
      print(doc.id);
    }
  });
```

This will fetch all documents where the `users` array contains `auth_id`. You can secure this with the following security rules (assuming auth_id is UID of current user):

```
match /collection/{docId} {
  allow read: if request.auth.uid in resource.data.users;
}
```

Comment: @Ahamed did you read the second half of my answer? If you store an array field then you can get data in a single query.

Comment: actually, already so much data already exists. Maybe if i follow your solution i need to run a query and add the array field. thank you for you answer